# How do you get wordpress plugin shortcode to $_GET url parameters

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a plugin on a page update-data which has a shortcode on the page of  [updatedata]

here is what an update row looks like

```
<td><a href="<?php echo admin_url('http://localhost/update-data&id='.$id); ?>">UPDATE</a></td>
```

Here is what the plugin code is

```
<?php
    /*
    plugin name: deano plugin update
    description: deano test database to update data into books table
    author: Dean-O

    */
    $path = preg_replace('/wp-content.*$/', '', __DIR__);
    require_once($path.'/wp-load.php');

    error_log("here");  // echos to log file
    error_log(var_dump($id));  // echos a blank line to the log file
    error_log("here 2"); // echos to the log file

    function deanoupdatedata($atts, $content = null ) {
        $a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'id' => 'id'
        ), $atts );
    
        return '<a id="' . esc_attr($a['id']) . '</a>';   // never displays
    }
    add_shortcode('updatedata','deanoupdatedata');
?>
```

How can I get the url parameter id in the plugin when I click on update link?

Answer (score 0):

Try `if($_GET['id'])` instead of `isset` and istead of `error_log` use `var_dump` to get the exact value

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice. You should pass the data to a shortcode using the shortcode's attributes.

Comment: can you show how?   I changed my shortcode to. [editdata id=""]. Still no luck. 

so with an edit href, with an id=x.  what does the shortcode need to look like and how do I get is in my plugin at the top>

myFuntion($id) { }

or how

Comment: @Dean-O you can use this [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232197/how-to-add-attributes-to-a-shortcode) as a reference

Comment: my href has the id=x in it.     My shortcode is simply [editdata]  so in my plugin at the top I have tried 
    function myfunction($id) {
        error_log(var_dump($id));

and it doesn't show a value even though the href has the url%id=x for each line of data from the database.

Comment: at the top of my plugin I have the following just before the function itself and it never shows a value for the $id.        

    $path = preg_replace('/wp-content.*$/', '', __DIR__);
require_once($path.'/wp-load.php');

error_log("here");
error_log(var_dump($id));
error_log("here 2");

Comment: I edited the initial question showing the code and the href calling the code

Comment: @Calculuswhiz are you responding to kaydash or me?  I updated my question showing the code and the href line but still I cant get the id value.  How is a url parameter obtained when using shortcodes for a plugin?